# How to swipe images in Android?

Tags: android

I am working on Android. I kept images in `GridView`. Now when I click on any image that image should display in seperate screen and from there the remaining images should also open while swiping. How can I achieve that task? Please help me in this regard.

Comment: Show us what you have tried?

Answer (score 5):

Use a [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html).

The official tutorial is here: [Using ViewPager for Screen Slides](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html)

Answer (score -1):

Since you didn't actually explained so there can be no specific answer and here is a links you might use
1-using [PageAdapter](http://manchuandroiddeveloper.blogspot.com/2014/01/how-to-swipe-images-in-android.html/)
or you can use GestureDetector witch you can search in [here](http://developer.android.com/)
hope it would be helpful .